# Wordpress search with xmlrpc does not return the same results

Tags: php, wordpress, search, xml-rpc

I try two different methods for searching in my wordpress site, one by xmlrpc interface and one by `mysiteurl?s=term.`

The problem is that the searching of "term" through xmlrpc returns different results than the second method (number of posts and the posts themselves).

For `xmlrpc` I use the `wp.getPosts` with parameter `s=term` and `number=100.`

Is it possible to obtain the same results through the two methods?

Thank you!

Comment: See the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts , there is a difference between `wp.getPost` and `wp.getPosts`

Comment: I am using `wp.getPosts` since I want to search for "term" in all published posts. 
`wp.getPost` returns a specific post if I am not mistaken.